# Antd filtering not working correctly, client code is executed but no filtering happeans

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, antd

I am trying to follow this page sample:
https://ant.design/components/table/

The antd filtering sample to be precise

I have a column which I know its 2 possible values only.
I can see in the debugger that the handlechange event is executed, but after click OK in the filter, the table is not filtered as it should

My best guess I am missing something on the OnFilter event

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {  Table, Tag, Button} from 'antd';
import { adalApiFetch } from '../../adalConfig';
import Notification from '../../components/notification';

class ListPageTemplatesWithSelection extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: [],
            filteredInfo: null,
            sortedInfo: null,
        };
        this.handleChange= this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.clearFilters= this.clearFilters.bind(this);
        this.clearAll= this.clearAll.bind(this);

    }

    handleChange(pagination, filters, sorter){
      console.log('Various parameters', pagination, filters, sorter);
      this.setState({
        filteredInfo: filters,
        sortedInfo: sorter,
      });
    }

    clearFilters(){
      this.setState({ filteredInfo: null });
    }

    clearAll(){
      this.setState({
        filteredInfo: null,
        sortedInfo: null,
      });
    }

    fetchData = () => {
        adalApiFetch(fetch, "/PageTemplates", {})
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(responseJson => {
            if (!this.isCancelled) {
                const results= responseJson.map(row => ({
                    key: row.Id,
                    Name: row.Name,
                    SiteType: row.SiteType,
                    Tags: row.Tags
                  }))
              this.setState({ data: results });
            }
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
          });
      };


    componentDidMount(){
        this.fetchData();
    }

    render(){
          let { sortedInfo, filteredInfo } = this.state;
        sortedInfo = sortedInfo || {};
        filteredInfo = filteredInfo || {};

        const columns = [
                {
                    title: 'Id',
                    dataIndex: 'key',
                    key: 'key',
                }, 
                {
                    title: 'Name',
                    dataIndex: 'Name',
                    key: 'Name',
                }, 
                {
                    title: 'Site Type',
                    dataIndex: 'SiteType',
                    key: 'SiteType',
                    filters: [
                      { text: 'Modern Team Site', value: 'Modern Team Site' },
                      { text: 'CommunicationSite', value: 'CommunicationSite' },
                    ],
                    filteredValue: filteredInfo.name || null,
                    onFilter: (value, record) => record.Tags.includes(value),
                },{
                  title: 'Tags',
                  key: 'Tags',
                  dataIndex: 'Tags',
                  render: Tags => (
                    <span>
                    {Tags && Tags.map(tag => {
                      let color = tag.length > 5 ? 'geekblue' : 'green';
                      if (tag === 'loser') {
                        color = 'volcano';
                      }
                      return <Tag color={color} key={tag}>{tag.toUpperCase()}</Tag>;
                    })}
                  </span>
                  ),
                }
        ];

        const rowSelection = {
            selectedRowKeys: this.props.selectedRows,
            onChange: (selectedRowKeys) => {
              this.props.onRowSelect(selectedRowKeys);
            }
          };


        return (
          <div>
            <Button onClick={this.clearFilters}>Clear filters</Button>
            <Button onClick={this.clearAll}>Clear filters and sorters</Button>
            <Table rowSelection={rowSelection}  columns={columns} dataSource={this.state.data} onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ListPageTemplatesWithSelection;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `SiteType` column, you have mistakenly set `filteredValue` prop to `filteredInfo.name`. But the filter is not on a `name` column, it is on `SiteType` column.

Change this line from:

```
filteredValue: filteredInfo.name || null,
```

To:

```
filteredValue: filteredInfo.SiteType || null,
```

And it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need execute the `fetchData` function in the `handleChange` function. Add filter params to ajax request. Just like this:

```
  handleTableChange = (pagination, filters, sorter) => {
    const pager = { ...this.state.pagination };
    pager.current = pagination.current;
    this.setState({
      pagination: pager,
    });
    this.fetch({
      results: pagination.pageSize,
      page: pagination.current,
      sortField: sorter.field,
      sortOrder: sorter.order,
      ...filters,
    });
  }
```

Comment: I dont understand this code, do I need to refactor my fetchdata method as well?]

Comment: Maybe I forgot to mention, the results will be very small, I dont want want to filter on the server side, it will never be more than 50 records, so I want to filter on the client side to avoid more http requests.

Comment: Yes, like another answer said. Your filteredValue must be same   with dataIndex.